# If statement in for loop -infinite loop

Tags: c, if-statement, for-loop

I have the following code where i run a nested for loop and inside the loop i check if the statment is true. If so, a kernel is loaded and convolution is performed with the kernel. Primary is the input image.

When i run the code, it becomes an infinite loop. I do not understand why.

```
for(m=0;m<h;m++)
{
    for(k=0;k<v;k++)
    {        
        if( (m = 261) && (k=361))
        { 
            printf("%f", Thickness[m][k]);
            printf("%d,%d",m,k);
            sprintf(fn,"F:\\newresult\\fft\\neww8_25.raw");
            if ((f2=fopen( fn, "rb" )) == NULL)
            {
                printf("Pb lecture fichier %s\n", fn);
                exit(1);
            }
            for(int a = 0; a < krow; ++a)
                for(int b = 0; b < kcol; ++b)
                    fread(&Kernel[a][b], sizeof(float), 1, f2);
            fclose(f2);
            for(int a = 0; a < krow; ++a)
                for(int b = 0; b < kcol; ++b)
                    sum+=Kernel[a][b];
            for(int a = 0; a < krow; ++a)
                for(int b = 0; b < kcol; ++b)
                    Kernel[a][b] /= sum;
            //convolute 
            s1 = convolve2D(primary, s1, m, k, Kernel, krow , kcol);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you enable compiler warnings the compiler will helpfully point out simple mistakes such as `if( (m = 261) && (k=361))`.

Comment: i think if( (m = 261) && (k=361)) this should be if( (m == 261) && (k==361))

Comment: The statement `if ((m = 261) && (k=361))` will always be true and as well set `m` and `k` to these values. We don't know what `h` and `v` are, but they are smaller than 261 and 361. You want comparison for equality, `==`, not assignment, `=`, here.

Comment: thank u very much. and if i have to put greater that or less than ?

Comment: Greater than or less than are always comparisons. There's no confusion.

Comment: Interestingly, in the line `if ((f2=fopen( fn, "rb" ))==NULL)`, you already use these two distinct operators correctly.

Comment: @user3840066 If any of these answers helped you, you **should** mark it as *accepted answer*.

Comment: m = 261 means you add value to m variable, but m == 261 in if statement means to check if m have value of 261.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if ((m = 261) && (k=361))` This is an assignment.
If you want to compare something:

- for equality, use `==`
- for less/greater: `<`/`>`
- for non-equality: `!=`

---

```
if(f2 == nullptr)
if(!f2)
```

Both cases are equal. If f2 **is** null, then...

```
if(f2 != nullptr)
if(f2)
```

If f2 **is not** null, then...

---

**Note:** *nullptr* is the c++11 feature. If you are not using c++11, use *NULL* insead.

**Edit:** As @unwind commented, there are two assignments.
Since `261` is always non-zero, 1st condition is always true. It will continue to evaluate the right hand side and assign `361` to `k`.

Comment: It's actually *two* assignments, since `261` is always non-zero the `&&` will continue and evaluate the right hand side, assigning to `k` too. :)

Answer (score 1):

your are assigning value to `m` here : `if( (m = 261) && (k=361))` which is always true (because it is non-zero value). 
it should be 
 `if( (m == 261) && (k==361))`